# Need to find a way to copy and paste type="password"

Tags: javascript, html

Got an assignment to find a way to enable copy function on type="password", I'm thinking that the best approach is with js, I would appreciate any help! thanks

Comment: What is copy function?

Comment: Can you please be more specific with your question? What exactly you want to achieve? Whats the use case?

Comment: *Pasting* into a password field is fairly normal and browsers handle it automatically. *Copying* from a password field is extremely weird and browsers disable it. So I would push back on this "assignment," it's not a problem worth solving.

Comment: generally, on stack overflow you need to come in and clearly present the problem you are having and provide some code of the things you have tried. The best way to learn is to actually do, and then ask for help when you have issues. ppl don't want to do your work for you, they just want to help you get past your blocker. This (along with lack of clarity) is why you are getting downvotes. I am not going to downvote you but It's useful to understand why ppl get downvoted. Go take a crack at your problem then come back here if you can't make it work :)

Comment: I think he means that: he has a password field with '*******' showing, and he wants to copy the content of that field and then paste it somewhere and it would show the actual content, eg: '**********' would be 'helloworld', as an example

Answer (score 2):

*Pasting* into a password field is fairly normal and browsers handle it automatically. *Copying* from a password field is extremely weird and browsers disable it. So I would push back on this "assignment," it's not a problem worth solving.

But you'd solve it with:

- An event handler (perhaps on a button next to the password field)
- Reading the value of the password field via its `value` property
- Using the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), specifically the [`writeText` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText), to write that password to the clipboard

But again, it's not something I'd suggest doing.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use a input type text with a 'password-dot-font' like [this one](https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1106896/password_dots_2)

Comment: Tbh, this does NOT sound like an assignment lol, sounds more like someone trying to find a way to find someones password

Comment: @Lumpenstein - Heh, quite. :-)